# There may be corrections made in

Tags: meaning

> There may be remediations MADE in your report.

When are they made? In the future or the past?

> 1 There may be remediations MADE in your report TOMORROW.
>
> 2 There may be remediations MADE by Helen in your report YESTERDAY.

Are both meanings valid?

Comment: Note that ["remediations" is barely English.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remediations%2Ccorrections&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Grammatically, the main verb could be "may be made" (modal verb+passive) or "may be" (accompanied by a subordinate clause with the participle made)

Comment: Do you mean "may + be made" and "may be + made"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, it depends on context.

1. Someone may make corrections when the report is discussed tomorrow.
2. We haven't yet seen the report; we may find that Helen made corrections yesterday.